# Reduce the time consumed by api in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

These are the models that I created i.e. Video, Tag, Category, Exercise and Package_Exercise respectively. and i want to fetch data based on the object in package exercise and fetch all the data from the Exercise i.e. video url, tag and category of each exercise. I wrote the code but its taking too much time how do I reduce the time taken by the code? What should be the best approach to handle these kind of situations? What would be the best approach based on the time complexity.

```
class Video(models.Model):
video = models.FileField(upload_to='videos_uploaded',null=False,validators=[FileExtensionValidator(allowed_extensions=['MOV','avi','mp4','webm','mkv'])])
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to="video_thumbnails",null=False)
description = models.TextField(max_length=200)
created_by = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='videos_created_by')
updated_by = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='videos_updated_by')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Tag(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Category(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                     related_name='catagoery_created_by')
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                    related_name='catagoery_exercise_updated_by')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Exercise(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False)
    description=models.TextField(max_length=300,null=False)
    video=models.ForeignKey(Video,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=False)
    category=models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=False)
    tag=models.ManyToManyField(Tag,null=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                   related_name='exercise_created_by', null=False)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                                    related_name='exercise_updated_by', null=False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Package_Exercise(models.Model):
  package = models.ForeignKey(Package,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='package')
  exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  repetition = models.IntegerField()
  number_of_sets = models.IntegerField() 
  rest_time = models.IntegerField() 
  created_by = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                              related_name='packages_exercise_created_by')
  updated_by = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                              related_name='packages_exercise_updated_by')
```

Here is the serializer takes **2.3s for ~30 objects of data** in the models.

```
class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   
    exercises = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model=Package
        fields= ['id','package_name','description','amount','is_public','public_doctor','thumbnail','exercises']


def get_exercises(self, obj):
    pkg_exercies = Package_Exercise.objects.filter(package = obj.id)
    sam = []
    for each in pkg_exercies:
        sam.append(
            {
                "name":each.exercise.name,
                "url":each.exercise.video.video.url,
                "description":each.exercise.description,
                "category":each.exercise.category.title,
                "tag":each.exercise.tag.name
            }
        )
    return sam
```

**What are the ways to tackle these kind of situations in both POST and GET APIs**

Comment: This is a classic 1 + N query bug situation. I recommend you read Matt Layman's article on Django performance https://www.mattlayman.com/understand-django/go-fast/. In short, use `select_related`. I'd also abstract away the use of `select_related` with custom managers or custom querysets. The official documentation is a great starting point.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new serializer for the package_excercise model and use it in PackageSerializer's method like this:

```
    def get_exercises(self, obj):
        pkg_exercies = Package_Exercise.objects.filter(package = obj.id)
        serializer = ExcerciseSerializer(data=pkg_exercies, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid()
        return serializer.data
```

In this way, you will be using the best way possible for fetching desired data moreover you will not have to repeat the same code in the future.